# how to configure 'dispatcherServlet' load on startup by spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent and add `spring-boot-starter-web` as denpendency.

By add the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, it works.

But `DispatcherServlet` need initialization

```
     Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
     FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
     Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@745f40ac]
     Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@219fc57d]
     Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@7b4bd6bd]
     Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@71ccfa36]
     Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@43f3e6a9]
     Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
     FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 37 ms
```

---

I hope I can set it's loadonstartup by 1, and don't want to use this 
annoying `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`, it rejected everything and I'm not going to use it.

```
o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
```

I read the java-doc about `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`:

> This is the default implementation used by the org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet, along with org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping (on Java 5 and higher). Alternatively, SimpleUrlHandlerMapping allows for customizing a handler mapping declaratively.

That's all, I just want to change these two thing:

1. setLoadonStartup
2. don't use BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping

Beside that, other thing spring boot configure for me is very great, and I want to keep it.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

New reply to old post.  Seems this is easier to do with more recent versions of Spring Boot.  Just adding the property `spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup=1` works for me.

Comment: This solution works for `@RestController` but not working for controller redirecting to views.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with `loadOnStartup`. I solved it by using a custom `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to modify the `BeanDefinition` of the `ServletRegistrationBean` that Spring Boot creates for registering the `DispatcherServlet`.

The following code will set `loadOnStartup` for the `DispatcherServlet` in a Spring Boot app, when used within an `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor() {
    return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(
                ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            BeanDefinition bean = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(
                    DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);

            bean.getPropertyValues().add("loadOnStartup", 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` is harmless here.

It is used to map a Spring Bean to a URL - for example it might be used to support Spring HttpInvoker remoting.

The rejection lines in the log output simply mean that it doesn't recognize any of the Spring beans as beans that require a URL mapping.  Annoying messages but harmless.  You could always set the logging level for this bean or its package to INFO or above to remove the message.  In Spring Boot's `application.properties` put

`logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.handler=INFO`